# Getting click information of website users with Javascript and loading click information to SQL database

Tags: javascript, sql, dom-events

I want to record click information, that I get from a website with Javascript code, to SQL database. How can I do that with a server side programming solution? Or is a client side solution better and how can I do?

Answer (score -1):

You may write a script in a programming language like a php or python.
For example: you have a php file like this:

```
<?php
$click_data = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['data']);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('dbname');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (data) VALUES ('".$click_data."')");
?>
```

Then, you may send post data to this script via XMLHttpRequest (ajax).

PS Sorry for my english =\